# Preparing regex for text

Tags: c#, regex

I have a piece of text:

```
"text 1

Sentence 1."*"the (1)
 /ðiː/

Sentence 1 Translated."
"text 2

Sentence 2."*"of (2)
 /əv/

Sentence 2 Translated."
"Text 3

Sentence 3!"*"and (3)
 /ænd/

Sentence 3 Translated!"
```

How to get values in such a division from `"` to the nearest `"`
Get them all as a collection

```
"text 1

Sentence 1."*"the (1)
 /ðiː/

Sentence 1 Translated."
```

I trying this, but not work:

```
"(.*?)""
```

Comment: Try `var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?sm)^("".*?"")\r?$").Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value);`. Or, if the quotes must be left out, `@"(?sm)^""(.*?)""\r?$"`

Comment: You can use this website to test your regexp: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/dotnet/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your example string, you need to get substrings from a `"` that is the first char on a line up to the first `"` that ends a line.

If you have the text inside a single variable, say `text`, you may use

```
var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?sm)^("".*?"")\r?$")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .Select(m => m.Groups[1].Value);
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fsm%29%5E%22%28.*%3F%29%22%5Cr%3F%24&i=%22text%201%0D%0A%0D%0ASentence%201.%22*%22the%20%281%29%0D%0A%20%2F%C3%B0i%CB%90%2F%0D%0A%0D%0ASentence%201%20Translated.%22%0D%0A%22text%202%0D%0A%0D%0ASentence%202.%22*%22of%20%282%29%0D%0A%20%2F%C9%99v%2F%0D%0A%0D%0ASentence%202%20Translated.%22%0D%0A%22Text%203%0D%0A%0D%0ASentence%203!%22*%22and%20%283%29%0D%0A%20%2F%C3%A6nd%2F%0D%0A%0D%0ASentence%203%20Translated!%22)

**Pattern details**

- `(?sm)` - `RegexOptions.Singleline` and `RegexOptions.Multiline` are on
- `^` - start of a line
- `("".*?"")` - Group 1: `"`, any 0+ chars but as few as possible, and a `"`
- `\r?` - an optional CR (as `$` does not match before a CR)
- `$` - end of line.